# How to remove unwanted character using hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a set of data :

```
coords=ARRAY(0x940044c)
Label<=>Bikini beach
coords=ARRAY(0x95452ec)
City=Y
Label=Naifaru%*
```

How do I remove the unwanted character to make it like this?

```
coords=ARRAY(0x940044c)
Label=Bikini beach
coords=ARRAY(0x95452ec)
City=Y
Label=Naifaru
```

I tried this:

```
hashChar = {"!"=>nil, "#"=>nil, "$"=>nil, "%"=>nil, "*"=>nil, "<=>"=>nil, "<"=>nil, ">"=>nil}

readFile.each do |char|
  unwantedChar = char.chomp
  puts unwantedChar.gsub(/\W/, hashChar)
end
```

But the output I will get is this:

```
coordsARRAY0x940044c
LabelBikinibeach
coordsARRAY0x95452ec
CityY
LabelNaifaru
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is not extremely long and you are fine to load it into memory, `String#gsub` would do. It’s always better to whitelist wanted characters, rather than blacklist unwanted ones.

```
readFile.gsub(/[^\w\s=\(\)]+/, '')

# coords=ARRAY(0x940044c)
# Label=Bikini beach
# coords=ARRAY(0x95452ec)
# City=Y
# Label=Naifaru
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the code you posted, that `readFile` is a `String` holding the *set of data* you are referring to.

```
puts readFile.delete('!#$<>*')
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Using a hash map with gsub

```rb
regex = Regexp.union(hashChar.keys)
puts your_string.gsub(regex, hashChar)
```

Comment: @RocheRdin https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union